# what does "it" indicate in "I was ashamed for anyone to know of my predicament, it was too stupid to be believed"?

Tags: antecedents

What does *it* indicate in this sentence?

> I was ashamed for anyone to know of my predicament, **it** was too stupid to be believed.
>
> —Ellison, *The Invisible Man*

Why it was too stupid?

Comment: "Why it was too stupid" is a matter for literary interpretation rather than English language and usage.

Comment: thank you for your opinion.

Comment: it=the predicament, in this case. Why is anything too stupid? You should know from your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "it" refers to Ellison's predicament.  If you were to edit your post to add a source link. I could tell you why he thought his predicament was, "Too stupid to be believed."

Comment: thank you for your help. by the way what does "to add a source pink" means? i don't know how to add it

Comment: Typo, I meant source LINK

Answer (score 0):

> I was ashamed for anyone to know of my predicament, **my predicament** was too stupid to be believed.

This sounds repetitive so the author has replaced "my predicament" with the pronoun "it".

I would need more context for the second part of your question. But as far as I remember, quite vaguely so, he wanted a girl to eavesdrop on the conversation between Mr. Norton and Mr. Bledsoe. The story of how Mr. Norton got injured and why the narrator fears being expelled because of it is too stupid. The narrator believes it's so stupid that people might not believe him altogether.

Please post links the next time you ask
about specific sections of a book.

Comment: thank you for your help! ^_^